# How to solve equality equation through matlab solver?

Tags: math, matlab, symbolic-math

I have a question related to basic mathematics, but with Matlab solving method. Here is the question:

```
y = 5;

for x=0.01:100
    F = 3*x + y - 2*x^2;
end
```

From the above iterative equation I want to find the max [F] value and its relative [x]. Is it possible to solve it through matlab solvers. Could you please help me to solve this problem?

Comment: Could you be please more specific and/or revise your question, code? e.g. `F` is not affected by the loop, moreover, with the given conditions `F` is a linear function...

Comment: sorry, i edited the question. Now F is changing in each iteration

Comment: It is still a linear function.

Comment: But the main problem is how to find max value of Function and its responding x value. Cause, applying the simple max() function does not show its responding x, or i do not know how to implement it.  And this is the basic equation, the real problem is non linear.

Comment: I think [this](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/choosing-a-solver.html) might be helpful.

Comment: Use linear programming.  Arpi's link above is useful.

Comment: Noted, I will try with them also. However, as i know the main limitation in this algorithms are their iteration number. Ex: 200 max iteration, which is too low for my original problem.

Comment: @Lab Your question is very unclear. What, exactly, is the function that you're trying to maximize? Is it a function of one (`x`) or two variables (`x` and `y`)? Is `y` fixed or not? If `y` is fixed and you want to maximise the function that, to a scalar `x`, associates `3*x + y - 2*x^2`, you can do that analytically...

Comment: The function is non linear and Y is fixed simple value, so there is just one variable that effects on changing of F function. And I want to go through extensive iteration to find the maximum F value and its responding x. Example: for x=0.01 value the F=15; when x=0.5, F=13; x=1, F=16. Hope you got what i want to say

Comment: @Lab Nope; your question still doesn't make any sense. If you evaluate your function of one variable at 0.01, you get a value. What is left to maximize?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For unconstrained non-linear optimization (according to your last edit) use [`fminsearch`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fminsearch.html) to solve your problem. It would be something like this:

```
F = @(x) 3*x + y - 2*x^2;
xini = 5; %initial value to the solver
[xsolu Fsolu] = fminsearch(@F,xini)
```

To control the options, parameters of solver see [`optimset`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/optimset.html)

```
opts = optimset('MaxFunEvals',10e4, 'MaxIter', 10e4)
[xsolu Fsolu] = fminsearch(@F,xini, opts)
```

---

The solution according to your original formulation would be:

```
x=0.01:100;
F = zeros(length(x),1);
for ii = 1:length(x)
    F(i) = 3*x(i) + y - 2*x(i)^2;
end

xsolu = max(F);
Fsolu = F(x == xsolu);
```

Which is quite inefficient approach, to say nothing more.

Comment: Really? `fminsearch` for a quadratic function? A bit overkill...

Comment: He/she changed the `F` function three times up to now, therefore I provided a general solution.

Comment: I agree.  The OP can't seem to make up their mind, so give them an overkill tool and let them figure it out for themselves.

Comment: Thank you for the solution. But are their any simple method, where i can use basic iterative algorithm, cause these algorithms are time consuming

Comment: Yes. You can use Newtons method, but that's assuming your function is differentiable. You can check my post on the Newton Raphson method here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25130693/3250829